# ExpressJS app.use("/" router) router.get("/") Breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm not sure how to phrase this, but part of the following code, for lack of an appropriate term, doesn't work. If I try to go to `localhost:3000/` it doesn't send back a response. I'm using Express 4.7.4 and the latest node available on the Ubuntu Trusty repository.

**app.js**

```js
///// Dependencies & config
var express = require('express');


///// Bootstrapping
//// Prepare Express
var server = express();

/// Configure Express
server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


/// Routers
var infoR = express.Router();

// This doesn't send anything back
infoR.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render('common/home');
});
// This works perfectly
infoR.get("/something", function(req, res) {
  res.render('info/something');
});

// Routes that work
server.use('/admin', require('./routes/admin'));
server.use('/account', require('./routes/account'));
server.use('/', infoR); // This is where the problem starts


///// Start the server
server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: "latest node available on the Ubuntu Trusty repository" get into the habit of compiling node from source - many repositories host old, outdated, and possibly insecure versions of node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating Express to version 4.9.

**Edit**: Turns out I've been doing it wrong, as noted in [the documentation](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x#no-more-appuseapprouter).